# Error when building for IOS

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I am having the following error when building for ios

```
ld: file too small (length=0) file '/Users/………./.robovm/cache/ios/x86/default/Users/    ……/.m2/repository/org/robovm/robovm-dist/0.0.13/unpacked/robovm-0.0.13/lib/robovm-   rt.jar/java/nio/PipeImpl$PipeSinkChannel.class.o' for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
:ios:launchIPhoneSimulator FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Any ideas? The desktop configuration is working. The JDK is 1.7+

I have installed the latest gradle setup for libgdx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See for solution here: https://github.com/robovm/robovm/issues/238

You need to remove zero-length class from cache and run build again.